# How can I fix this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'borderBottom' of undefined at "MyClassName" "?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the style of a button whenever Someone click on it and I'm trying to do this with a function that I wrote in the JavaScript file but it doesn't work and it gives this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'borderBottom' of undefined at SignUp_Click".

```js
function SignUp_Click() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("Sign_up").style.borderBottom = "12px solid #c00000";
}
```

```css
.Sign_up {
    float: right;
    height: 93px;
    width: 115px;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
}

    .Sign_up input[type=button] {
        border: none;
        direction: rtl;
        font-size: 16pt;
        color: #262626;
        background: url('images/sign_up.png') right center no-repeat;
        padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
        margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Sign_up"> <input type="button" value="Sign up" onmousedown="SignUp_Click()"/> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTML Collection of all elements that have the specified class, not just one element, use either, `document.querySelector('.Sign_up')` to get the first element with the class `Sign_up`, or index the collection returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```js
function SignUp_Click() {
  // or document.querySelector('.Sign_up') but without [0]
  document.getElementsByClassName("Sign_up")[0].style.borderBottom = "12px solid #c00000";
}
```

```css
.Sign_up {
  float: right;
  height: 93px;
  width: 115px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
}

.Sign_up input[type=button] {
  border: none;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: #262626;
  background: url('images/sign_up.png') right center no-repeat;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
  margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Sign_up"> <input type="button" value="Sign up" onmousedown="SignUp_Click()" /> </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns HTMLCollection, not a single element.

So you should use something like to select the first element of the collection:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("Sign_up")[0].style.borderBottom = "12px solid #c00000";
```

Or use `document.querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector(".Sign_up").style.borderBottom = "12px solid #c00000";
```

which returns the first of the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way you are selecting your button is the issue. I would also consider giving it an ID and selecting it that way! (getElement**s**ByClassname returns a collection!)

```js
function SignUp_Click() {
    document.querySelector(".Sign_up").style.borderBottom = "12px solid #c00000";
}
```

```css
.Sign_up {
    float: right;
    height: 93px;
    width: 115px;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
}

    .Sign_up input[type=button] {
        border: none;
        direction: rtl;
        font-size: 16pt;
        color: #262626;
        background: url('images/sign_up.png') right center no-repeat;
        padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
        margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Sign_up"> <input type="button" value="Sign up" onmousedown="SignUp_Click()"/> </div>
```